# Proof that $|\sin z|<|z\cos z|$ for $z=x+iy$ such that $\max\{|x|,|y|\}=n\pi$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to prove the following inequality
$$|\sin z|<|z\cos z|$$
for all $z=x+iy$ such that $\max\{|x|,|y|\}=n\pi$, $n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$.

> If $z=n\pi+i\alpha$, where $|\alpha|\leq |n\pi|$, we have 
>   $$|\sin z|=|\sinh \alpha|\quad\text{ et }\quad |\cos z|=|\cosh\alpha|.$$
>   As $|\tanh x|-|x|\leq 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, it follows that
>   $$|\sin z|=|\sinh \alpha|\leq |\alpha||\cosh \alpha|< |z||\cosh \alpha|=|z\cos z|.$$

Now I have to prove the inequality in the case $z=\alpha+in\pi$.

Using that $\sin z = (e^{iz}-e^{-iz})/2i$ and $\cos z = (e^{iz}+e^{-iz})/2$ and doing a huge lot of manipulations I got to prove it. However, I think it may exist a simpler solution (like the one I did for the other case). Maybe letting $w=-iz$ and then using the first case? (I couldn't make this work but maybe someone here can.)

I would like to see if anyone has a nice proof of this result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to prove
$$2\sin z\>\sin\bar z<z\>\bar z\cdot 2\cos z\>\cos\bar z\ ,$$
or $$\cos(z-\bar z)-\cos(z+\bar z)<z\bar z\bigl(\cos(z-\bar z)+\cos(z+\bar z)\bigr)\tag{1}$$
for $z=\alpha+in\pi\>$ with $n\geq1$ and $|\alpha|\leq n\pi$. Now $(1)$ amounts to
$$-\cos(z+\bar z)<{z\bar z-1\over z\bar z+1}\>\cos(z-\bar z)\ ,$$
or
$$-\cos(2\alpha)<{|z|^2-1\over|z|^2+1}\>\cosh(2n\pi)\ .\tag{2}$$
Since $|z|^2\geq n^2\pi^2>9$ and $\cosh(2\pi)>267$ the inequality $(2)$ is obviously true for all real $\alpha$ and $n\geq1$.